Can I load char driver on already existing device node?
I am exploring Linux kernel driver programming. And stumbled with following thoughts,

Can I load a char driver on already existing device node (device node may already be created using mknod) ?
To further extend #1, can one char driver create a device node which is then consumed by another char driver to register and load itself against the created device node using node's major/minor number?

Do we have any example where it is already being used?

this sounds pretty confusing, both to the user as well as to the driver developer. The registration of that char device driver should fail, when there's a number conflict. (never tried - this seems a bit of a strange idea!) So, assuming I'm right that this is impossible: what it is that you want to achieve? The way your solution sounds is a bit surprising, but maybe the problem simply has a straightforward solution :)
